# Java Game Programming with JFrames

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am interested in Java game programming, but I want to do it with JFrames not applets. I was wondering if there were any tutorial websites that would show me how, because all of the ones I found were about applets. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading this message.

Comment: You need to increase your Google search skills.

Comment: Anything related to rendering that can be done in an applet can be done in a `JComponent` or `JPanel`.  Move the rendering code to one of those two, set a preferred size, drop it into a `JFrame` and your basically done.  See [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for more details on making a GUI in a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/reference/programming/languages/java/java-games-active-rendering-r2418) for details on this.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of tutorials and help at [Java-Gaming.org](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/board,65.0.html). Friendly people, too.
The link I put in is where they've gathered some tutorials. Good luck!